# JQuery toggleClass is not toggling my classes and collapsing div width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked all over and nothing has helped me fix my issue.

Basically im trying to collapse a div on the left of my page and when i click a button it collapses in therefore hiding the navbar.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navbar').click(function() {
    $('#navbar').toggleClass('#navbar-clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(000, 000, 000);
  background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
}
#navbar-clicked {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <div style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px;">[TEXTLOGO]</div>
</div>
```

**I've fiddled with this code in code pen but i can't get it to collapse the DIV**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes can't start with `#`, only IDs can. That would result in a class with selector `.#navbar-clicked` and is not valid CSS.

What you're looking for is `#navbar.clicked` (translating to: element with the id "navbar" that has the class "clicked").

See this working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#navbar').click(function()
  {
        $('#navbar').toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
#navbar
    {
        position: fixed;
        width: 15%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgb(000, 000, 000);
        background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.7);
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
    }

#navbar.clicked
    {
        width: 0%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
        <div style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px;">[TEXTLOGO]</div>
</div>
```

Another problem is, that you are completely hiding the navbar, so there's no possibility to display it again. You probably want to leave a portion of it visible, maybe with an icon that makes it clear to the user that he can click to expand the navigation again.

Comment: I've copied your code into code pen and its still not working http://codepen.io/Magicrecon/pen/ggEKKW whats different?

Comment: You should definitely make yourself familiar with the development tools, especially the console. There, you would have seen the error message `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, which would have told you that jQuery is simply not included. If you add jQuery to your external dependencies, it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egXKPX

Comment: Ah brilliant i'll do that, all part of the learning curve, so thank you for your help, your answer has got the green tick :)